# How to proceed with video card(black screen)

Tags: video, graphics-card, display, troubleshooting, computer-building

I built a computer on Saturday and it was working for the weekend. I was able to post, download an OS, and even benchmark some games. However, on Monday I was informed that the video card stopped outputting video.

When the computer is turned on, the case fan, CPU fan, and graphics card fan all turn on and the computer seems to run. However, all that is displayed is a black screen. Not even the BIOS manufacturer logo shows up. I have confirmed that when the video card is removed and we plug our HDMI cable into the motherboard then we are able to see again and even get to Windows.

How should I proceed with this?

Hardware Description:

- Motherboard: Gigabyte h110m-a
- CPU: intel i3 6100
- Graphics Card: PNY gtx 1060 6gb
- Power Supply: EVGA 430 80+
- Storage: 2tb refurbished toshiba drive
- RAM: G-Skill NT memory 1x 8gb

Another thing that might be important is that our TV (what we are using for a monitor) specifically says 'no signal' when it doesn't sense a video signal. However, when the GPU is plugged in this message does away. I think that some sort of video is being outputted but all we see is a black screen.

Answer (score 0):

If you have connected the video card output to another normal monitor and still can not see an image, then return your video card. It is defective.

If however you see an image from the video card and know it is not defective, then while it is connected to a monitor where you can see the output correctly, change the resolution setting and especially the Hz to match the TV you are trying to connect to BEFORE you plug it into the TV.  Probably needs to be 1080P at 59 or 60Hz.  Also, you might want to update your video card drivers to the latest before doing this.

Answer (score 0):

From your description you are able to output video when the internal graphic card (builtin) Intel® HD Graphics 530 is working, what could mean the following issue:

Your power supply is designed only for [430 watts](http://evga.com/Products/Product.aspx?pn=100-W1-0430-KR), but your GPU needs at least [400 watts](https://www.pny.com/geforce-gtx-1060) (look under specification) to operate, whereas it will consume around 120W (again it could depend on the ways how you use your GPU). But this is only GPU you also need to consider CPU, RAM, HD, all fans and all of the connected peripherals (USB hubs, keyboard, mouse, printer, scanner, memory sticks, memory cards, etc.). Usually people purchase PSU with a thought of inevitable future upgrades as well as keeping a safety gap 150-200W just in case some numbers were wrong on the hardware manufacturer specs.

I would make a guess that you have successfully "fried" your newly purchased video card. Try returning you GPU to the retailer, explain the situation and hope for their loyalty.

My advise would be using a [power supply calculator](http://www.coolermaster.com/power-supply-calculator/) in order to identify how much power you actually need - I have tried to input your config into calculator and it gave me around 550W, but it could be more. Plan carefully what components exactly you need to purchase, otherwise you end up wasting money on hardware.